# DBIx::Class how to retrieve generated UUID on create?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have an application that uses `DBIx::Class`, currently when I create an object that corresponds to a table I get back the object but the `id` column will be set to `0` instead of to the `UUID` that's generated on the database level. How can I properly retrieve the `id` column when I create a new record?

Here is my table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log (
    id VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT (UUID()) PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
```

Here is my `DBIx::Class` schema:

```perl
__PACKAGE__->load_components(qw/InflateColumn::DateTime PK::Auto Core/);

__PACKAGE__->table('log');
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
    id => {
        data_type         => 'varchar',
        size              => 36,
        unique            => 1,
        is_auto_increment => 1
    },
    qw/.../ # other columns
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key('id');
```

When I go to insert, like (`log_repository` is my resultset):

```perl
my $log = $self->log_repository->create($json);

print $log->get_column('id'); # 0 instead of valid UUID
```

How can I retrieve the `UUID` on create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one way to solve it, though it isn't pretty, and far from what i'd like to do, it works.

In my `ResultSet` classes, I over-wrote the `create` method to append a pre-generated UUID to the `id` field before executing the super-classes' create like so:

```perl
sub create {
    my $self = shift;
    my $qry  = shift;

    return $self->SUPER::create( { %{$qry}, id => Data::UUID->new->create_str } );
}
```

Then I can call `create` like usual, and get the `id` back.